# Laravel Eager Loading - Load (Hace cosas raras)

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando cargar las encuestas  de un grupo, lo cual si se muestran, pero también quiero recuperar el nombre de quien hizo esa encuesta.

Así es como tengo mi controlador:

```html
  public function index(Grupo $grupo)
    {   

        $grupo->load('Encuestas.users');

        return view('Encuesta.index',compact('grupo'));
    }
```

Bueno, para que se muestren las encuestas con su respecto usuario de quien la creoó.

en el modelo `Encuesta`

```html
    public function users()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
    }
```

¿No entiendo porque debo de poner user_id. sino lo pongo no funciona.
"no sé por que" no lo tenía que hacer así en otras cosas que había hecho..

Bueno entonces, Hago un return. Y me muestra toda la información, pero  cuando la muestro en una vista blade.

Muestro cada encuesta- Pero al momento de mostrar el nombre del usuario quien creó esa encuesta. me sale un problema de

**n+1**

lo cual es un problema, Entonces. NO sé como solucionar eso, Ya que según si carga la información del usuario quien creó esa encuesta.

luego, Necesito paginarlo. Lo cual tampoco me deja

Entonces decidi hacer esto.

```html
   public function index(Grupo $grupo)
    {   

        $grupo = Grupo::with(['encuestas.users'])
        ->where('id',$grupo->id)->first();

        return view('Encuesta.index',compact('grupo'));
    }
```

Ahora no tengo el **problema de n+1**

pero, hago doble consulta, Lo cual tampoco el Paginate me funciona
 es claro que si quito el first poner paginate. pero no me sirve

posiblmente
porque  solamnete me muestra un grupo lo cual ese grupo tiene encuestas. Necesito paginar las encuestas.

---

Pudiera hacer todo más simple, haciendo la consulta  a la tabla encuestas  poniendo como where el grupo a la que pertence.

pero quiero intentar hacerlo con el load. que el grupo lo estoy pasando por  modelBinding.
Gracias

Comment: Es un poco confuso todo lo que explicas, sería más fácil de entender si nos muestras un dump de los resultados de cada etapa. Sería interesante también ver como están definidas las relaciones en Grupo.

Comment: @Shaz Quise ser claro, pero es que en resumen. cuando uso Load y quiero imprimirlo en una vista me sale un problema de n+1. y tampoco puedo paginar

Comment: ¿qué es lo que deseas paginar? grupos, encuestas o usuarios. ¿qué tipo de relaciones hay entre estos 3?